What is the solution of the 2nd-order differential equation with this sign function?
I want to find the roots of a 2nd-order differential equation that contains a sign function.
$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}-μmgcosθsgn\frac{dx}{dt}+kx=0$
By analyzing the time-displacement graph of this motion, I can infer that it is a damped oscillation, specifically a low-damped motion. (It will behave like this when some force is greater than some other force, but I'm not sure of the initial conditions for this).
I am a student. I was solving a problem related to physics and wanted to explore further, so I came up with the following expression.
As an initial condition, $\frac{dx}{dt}(0)<0$. All the rest of the constants are just that, constants, so I would appreciate it if you could find $a\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}-bsgn\frac{dx}{dt}+cx=0$ for a low-damping-like motion. My limiting expression may not be correct, so if it doesn't work, consider changing the sign of the coefficients in the $\frac{dx}{dt}$ term.

This question appears from time to time, I just did not find now the right search words. The solution is a spiral formed of two sets of concentric semi-circles, in the right scaling of the phase space. One set is for $ßot x>0$, the other for the other half-plane.

For an oscillator with constant friction the force of the friction is always against the direction of velocity relative to the ground at rest $$m \ddot x = - k x  - f\  \text{sign} \  \dot x$$
It follows that the the solution has to be determined in the four sectors
$$ (\text{xmin}(s_k)= 0 < x < \text{xmax}(t_k) , \ 0< \dot x = v <\text{vmax}(t_k)),\quad (x>0, v < 0), \quad (x<0, v<0), \quad (x<0, v>0) $$
such that the pair $$t\mapsto (x(t),v(t))$$ is continuous at all the times $,s_k, t_k$ of zeros of $x$ and $v$.
With $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$ the solution of the ODE
$$ v(t)= \partial_t x(t) , \quad m \partial_{t,t} x(t)=-f \text{sgv}-k x(t),\quad x(0)=0,\quad v(0)=\text{v0} $$
is
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{m \omega^2} \left( \text{sgv} \ f  \ \cos ( \omega t ) \ - \  \text{sgv} \ f \  + \ m \ \text{v0} \ \sin (\omega t)\right)$$
